# remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied downloading local repo in gitlab

Tags: git, go, gitlab, gitlab-ci

There a lot of discussion on this topic, I read a lot but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Gitlab version 14.5.2

Gitlab runner version: 14.5.1 and running as shell

2FA is enabled and I have created my access token; I'm trying to compile a Golang program that use a library in my gitlab repo. Here my yml file

```
variables:
  REPOSITORY: $CI_REGISTRY/acme/test/master

before_script:
  - export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
  - go env -w GOOS=linux
  - go env -w GOARCH=amd64
  - go env -w GOPRIVATE=gitlab.acme.com

build_image:
  script: 
    - ssh-keyscan -t rsa gitlab.acme.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - echo -e "machine gitlab.acme.com\nlogin gitlab-ci-token\npassword ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc
    - git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.acme.com/".insteadOf git://gitlab.acme.com/
    - go mod download
    - go build
    - docker build -f Dockerfile -t $REPOSITORY:latest .
    - docker push $REPOSITORY:latest
    - docker rmi $(docker images $REPOSITORY -a -q)
    - rm $HOME/.netrc
```

The result is this:

```
go mod download: gitlab.acme.com/datamanent/go-commons@v0.0.0-20211221151250-f0220d428461: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /home/gitlab-runner/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/c9ecbc2c20382f733e0a04c852c63cb9a78c5166f9ae2d25864a2d7728490ddb: exit status 128:
    remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
    fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.acme.com/test/go-commons.git/'
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
```

If I don't use an internal lib, compile is fine and push in gitlab registry is ok as well.
If I try to clone the repo instead of doing **go mod download**, doing this:

```
- git clone git@gitlab.acme.com:test/go-commons.git
```

Of course it doesn't work I got this message:

```
cloning into 'go-commons'...
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@gitlab.acme.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
```

**--------------- UPDATE ---------------**

Thanks to @VonC I change the git directive to

```
git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.acme.com/".insteadOf \
                    git@gitlab.acme.com:
```

unfortunately this was still not enough, and it was really weird, so I add to the pipeline `cat $HOME/.gitconfig` I wanted to see if it was correctly added the directive. And what I see was that there were a lots of entries, most likely everytime I tried the pipeline, stupid me, I thought the file went away everytime I run the CI (but I'm in shell not in docker), so I delete it and now works.

Comment: Have you considered using SSH Key based  auth?  or does that not work with gitlab's 2fa?

Comment: Good catch, well done.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include your conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

In your test, you tried to clone using an SSH URL `git@gitlab.acme.com:...`, which did not work.
Replacing it be an HTTPS with credentials (including a token, to pass 2FA) would make sense.

But in your `git config`, you replace a Git URL `git://gitlab.acme.com/` (*not* an SSH URL).

Try and display `$REPOSITORY` first, to double check if it is an SSH or Git URL.
Because if it is an SSH one, you would need an `InsteadOf` directive like:

```
git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.acme.com/".insteadOf \
                    git@gitlab.acme.com:
```

The [OP NiBE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320479/nibe) adds

> I added to the pipeline `cat $HOME/.gitconfig`: I wanted to see if it was correctly added the directive.
>
> And what I see was that there were a lots of entries, most likely every time I tried the pipeline (I thought the file went away everytime I run the CI, but I'm in shell not in docker).
>
> So I delete it and now works.

Comment: Thanks @VonC I change the directive as you suggested and try for semplicity to clone the repo. What I got is : fatal: unable to update url base from redirection ....  redirect: https://gitlab.acme.com/users/sign_in  which seems to me a auth problem it seems like it does not like the token? or maybe I miss some configuration on gitlab side

Comment: I just tried this in the pipeline and it works:  git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.acme.com/test/go-commons so it seems I'm doing something wrong in the git redirect directive

Comment: @NiBE so you need to adapt your InsteadOf directive to emulate the URL which works