# Git Error with Go Build and Other Go Commands

Tags: git, go, permissions, repository

When trying to build in Go, I get the following Git error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What is the cause for this?

I am able to clone the same repository successfully using both HTTP and SSH and have the appropriate permissions assigned to it as confirmed by the GitLab UI.

I'm running MacOS Monterey.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's an ssh error, not a Git error: Git runs ssh, ssh fails, and then Git stops because it needed ssh to succeed. You can sometimes work around it by having Git use https instead of ssh (see VonC's answer), but if ssh *should* work, poke around with it (ssh, that is) to see why it *isn't* working.

Comment: You're right. It was an SSH issue. When I switched from SSH to HTTPS, everything worked. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 4):

Check your `go.mod` in the Go project you are compiling.

It might refer to modules who might be private, and that you might not have the right to clone.
Or you can force using HTTPS instead of SSH for any dependencies, [as I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70457512/6309).

The [OP Foobar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3825948/foobar) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74051189/git-error-with-go-build-and-other-go-commands/74051247#comment130787289_74051247):

```
git config --global url."gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.acme.com/".insteadOf git@gitlab.acme.com:
```

Comment: @Foobar Great, well done! What did you do to make it work?

Comment: I used the following as mentioned by you above: git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.acme.com/".insteadOf git@gitlab.acme.com:

Comment: @Foobar Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.